# HTK: E: Unable to locate package libx11-dev:i386

Tags: htk

apt-get install libx11-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libx11-dev:i386

Answer (score 0):

maybe you haven't enable i386 architecture,you can try execute these commands

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```